# Find $\int_{|z|=R} \frac{1}{(z-b)(z-a)^m} dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to find $\int_{|z|=R} \frac{1}{(z-b)(z-a)^m} dz$ for $|a| <R < |b|$ I would use Cauchy formula but first what can I do with $\frac{1}{(z-b)(z-a)^m}$? I dont remember it.

Comment: Does $$\int_{\lvert z\rvert = R} \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^m}\,dz$$ remind you of something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here $\dfrac{1}{(z-a)(z-b)^m}$ has pole of order $m$ at $z=a$ inside $|z|=R,$ therefore, 
by Cauchy's integral formula
\begin{align}
\int_{|z|=R}\dfrac{1/(z-b)}{(z-a)^n}dz&=\frac{2\pi i}{(m-1)!}\frac{d^{m-1}}{dz^{m-1}}\left(\frac{1}{z-b}\right)_{z=a}\\&=(-1)^{m-1}2\pi i\frac{1}{(a-b)^{m}}.
\end{align}